# Specifiying infix operators in Style

Tags: front-end, style, boxes

This has certainly been asked on MSE somewhere before. Where it is has eluded me the past 50 or so minutes.

I'm formatting some boolean expressions using [`Interpretation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpretation.html) and [`Defer`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Defer.html) to provide access to the expression without evaluation difficulties or formatting to deal with.

Problem is, I want to format, e.g. `And[a,b]` as `a\[And]b` not `a&&b`. I know I could get away with a `Row` since I'm using `Interpretation`, but I know there has to be some way at the `Style` level to specifiy that `And` should be formatted as `\[And]`.

Does anyone know where such a thing would be?

Just as a rehash, I'm looking for a `Style` (or similar) option to format `And` as `\[And]` instead of `&&`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this is a [`StandardForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StandardForm.html) question, you could do:

```
Unprotect[And];
And /: MakeBoxes[And[a__], StandardForm] := RowBox[
    BoxForm`MakeInfixForm[And[a],"\[And]",StandardForm]
]
Protect[And];
```

Or you could use [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm.html).

Comment: Forgot that `Style`  doesn't take `TraditionalForm` as an argument. `TraditionalForm` and `SingleLetterItalics -> False` gets the job done.